Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 403 in Gitlab Webhooks after updating Jenkins to Version 2.452.1
I have updated Jenkins to  2.452.1 version. After the update I am trying to trigger Merge request from Gitlab to jenkin, but for some reason my webhooks are not testing successfully. When I try to test the webhook manually I am getting the following error.
enter image description here
I have updated the secret token in webhook.

Please include the relevant configurations in the Question. Also, copy and paste the error text into the Question, if at all possible.
